# Jquery Datatable column resizing is not work as expected with 'columnDefs' column width is defined

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm using jquery datatable column width resizing functionality. I'm setting column width using `columnDefs` . 
like this

```
    columnDefs: [
        { className: "text-center", "targets": [4] },
        { className: "popover-right", "targets": [0] },
        { "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3], "width": "20%" },
        { "targets": [4], "width": "10%" }
    ],
```

My problem is, while setting the column width using this functionality my column resize functionality is not working as expected.

Here is the link what I'm expecting to work like

https://jsfiddle.net/Dhanil007/5e8wksyz/1/

Comment: can you share full html

Comment: @GöktenKaradağ sure , i will

Comment: @dhanil you can see example here click on [link] link('https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/26786/basic-column-resizing-plugin')

Comment: @dhanil and one more example here [link]('https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-reordering-and-resizing/')